# Rails, has_many :through, undefined method `to_sym` for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have been learning rails and i have stumbled one problem with relationships. I have many-to-many association User - Tournament, and for some reason i can't access participated_tournaments on User instances, or can't access participants on Tournament instances.

```
2.0.0-p643 :001 > Tournament.new.participants
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
from /home/marcin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:100:in `_reflect_on_association'
from /home/marcin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:537:in `source_reflection'
```

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participants_tournaments
  has_many :participated_tournaments, :through => :participants_tournaments
end
```

Tournament model

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participants_tournaments
  has_many :participants, :through => :participants_tournaments
end
```

ParticipantsTournament model

```
class ParticipantsTournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tournament
  belongs_to :user
end
```

ParticipantsTournament migration

```
def change
  create_table :participants_tournaments, :id => false do |t|
    t.integer "tournament_id",
    t.integer "user_id"
  end
end
```

I have read:
[This topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030407/many-to-many-relationship-only-works-one-way-rails-activerecord-devise), [also this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403819/has-many-through-association) and watched/read [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many), but i can't seem to finally get it working.

Comment: can you try `t = Tournament.new` followed by `t.participants`?

Comment: with has_many :through I'm pretty certain that the join table needs an id column for primary keys, so when you creating that table, make sure you delete `:id => false` in the migration.

Comment: @MaxHung  You do not need an id in a join table.  You only need ids for the things you are joining.

Comment: @sixty4bit yes, it would give me same output :) Ausio's answer is the correct one that really helped me, thanks though!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you are calling `.new` on tournaments it does not have an `id`, so it will be `nil`.  Therefore will not find the user.

Also when you are remapping a model in a has many through like this you have to tell active record what the model it is looking for is.  You do this with the `:source` argument.  Here is how tournament would work.

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participants_tournaments
  has_many :participants, :through => :participants_tournaments, :source => :user
end
```

Comment: Thanks! It makes a lot of sense with :source option but when i was googling earlier, it wasn't mentioned a lot. Thank you a lot!